# Why I can't install node_module with docker-sompose run command

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, node-modules

I have a express application. And I use the docker-compose to run it. To run my app I use command:

```
docker-compsoe up
```

If I run it at first time and don't have any node_modules - I have an error in terminal, sth like "The module 'express' not found, please install it and try again...". So, I just open one more terminal, and run next command:

```
docker-compose exec backend npm i
```

Modules are installed for a few seconds. And and my app start working in the previous terminal. I allways use this method, but now I found command `run` for docker-compose. It allows you to exec some command in container, when it is not raised. So I wanted to try this command and I deleted ./node_modules directory, stop all containers, close all terminals, open terminal and run command:

```
docker-compose run backend npm i
```

Modules started to install, I wait for about 10 minutes but it is stops in the middle. I don't understand why?  If I try `up` and `npm i` in second terminal it works, but with command `run` - not. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should not install your node modules in a running container. Instead, you shoud install it in your image via your Docker file and then run it via docker or docker-compose.

Your Dockerfile should look like something like this:

```
FROM node:10      # or the version of node you are using
WORKDIR /usr/src/app      #replace this with your app code path
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
COPY app-code/ /usr/src/app/app-code  # again, use your own path
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

You have to run `npm install` from your dockerfile and not copy your development node folder because the environment from the container may differ from your development environment.

Then you can just run it from your docker-compose file.

Comment: Ok, you install your node_modules to /usr/src/app. But if you use volumes `./:/usr/src/app` - they are become deleted because /node_modules isn't exist in your current directory on hostmachine.

Comment: I know, there are several methods how to install node_modules. And some people like to do it in image, another like to install in container at first time, bur ot is another question, i wondered why node_modules don't install with `run` command, but install with `exec` command.